# Leaving behind - meaning as an intransitive verb

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

As per collins dictionary: 
**leave behind**
in British English
VERB (transitive)

1. (adverb)
   to forget or neglect to bring or take
2. to cause to remain as a result or sign of something
   the storm left a trail of damage behind
3. to pass
   once the wind came up, we soon left the land behind us

I am unable to understand the third meaning in this list. What does "to pass" mean and the example actually makes it more difficult for me to understand this usage. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: It's actually dictionary.com, not Collins. I'm not sure why they define it as 'pass', but the example refers to a boat heading out to sea and away from the land.

Answer (score 1):

When you travel on the sea, you move through the water and leave the land behind you.

Another example. When one competitor in a race passes another and the gap between them increases, the leader leaves behind the slower competitor.

Comment: Thanks, it still doesn't make any sense why the meaning "to pass"